# Different result value between FFTS FFT and Matlab FFT

Tags: android, matlab, fft, dft

I am new to fft. I am converting code from Matlab to java/c to use in Android device. I can do this with pure java fft lib like Jtransform and Jwave but i want to use FFTS (https://github.com/anthonix/ffts) for native performance but the output not the same, i don't know why. I read on Matlab site they say about scaling (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15770-scaling-the-fft-and-the-ifft) but i can not find the scaling ratio to match two result value.

I update the output:
Matlab:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
X=fft(x,8);

28.0000000000000 + 0.00000000000000i    
-4.00000000000000 + 9.65685424949238i
-4.00000000000000 + 4.00000000000000i
-4.00000000000000 + 1.65685424949238i
-4.00000000000000 + 0.00000000000000i
-4.00000000000000 - 1.65685424949238i
-4.00000000000000 - 4.00000000000000i
-4.00000000000000 - 9.65685424949238i
```

FFTS:

```
FFTS fft = FFTS.real(FFTS.FORWARD, 8);
fft.execute(x,output);

28.000000 + 0.000000i
-4.000000 + 9.656855i
-4.000000 + 4.000000i
-4.000000 + 1.656854i
0.000000 + 0.000000i
0.000000 + 0.000000i
0.000000 + 0.000000i
0.000000 + 0.000000i
```

Comment: Do you have a small test output (e.g. 8 point FFT) from FFTS and Matlab?

Comment: @SleuthEye I have updated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real FFT (fft.real()) does not return the 2nd half of the result of a full FFT.  That is because, given strictly real input (not complex data types, or all imaginary components equal to zero), the FFT result is conjugate symmetric; thus the 2nd half is redundant (after conjugation).

A full FFT returns the 2nd half of the complex result vector, even if redundant.  (The 2nd half of a full FFT is non-redundant only if the input is complex with non-zero imaginary components.  An fft.real() does not allow this kind of input.)